# How to get the contents of a triangular shaped div to fill its shape?

Tags: python, html, css, text, shapes

I have got a triangle shaped div containing text

It is within a body and section header.
It fits a triangle shape but cuts off most the text and I can't get the text to fill the width of the triangle and cut off appropriately.

I'm not sure if the problem is needing the contents to fit the div, or the div to change to the contents, I've been experimenting with white-space, display, and overflow but can't figure it out.

```css
body { background-color: grey; }
.text-wrapper {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-width: 50% 0 50% 100%;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent red;
  clip-path: polygon(0 0, 100% 0, 50% 100%);
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  overflow: auto;
  line-height: 1;
}

.main-header {
  color: #256D85;
  font-size: 7.5rem;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.sub-header {
  color: #26B6E8;
  background-color: #06283D;
  font-size: 6rem;
  font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-wrapper">
  <p class="main-header">Text header</p>
  <p class="sub-header">Text sub-header</p>
  <p>description here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. I changed the background colour to show the triangle

Comment: What would you describe as ‘cut off appropriately’, for example do you want the text to shrink to fit?

Comment: @AHaworth I mean that the text is partially in a triangle shape but outside of the shape the text is hidden, but I want it to go onto a new line within the triangle div. The 'description here' has a paragraph of writing that I want to fit into the triangle and start a new line when it fills the width of that line in the shape. So basically have all my text in the triangle in a triangle shape, with nothing overflowing outside of the div.

Comment: Is shape-outside helpful here? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/shape-outside

Comment: @AHaworth That wraps text around the shape, but I want the text inside the shape?

Comment: Did you see the example given on that page, which is of text ‘funnelling’ which looked to me like exactly what you want (basically the text is outside two shapes).